# How to prevent inputting Russian characters in Word with a Word addin?

Tags: delphi, ms-word, internationalization

Sorry for this vaguely described problem, but please look at the problem from the Win32 API's perspective.

I'm writing a Word addin using Addin Express with Delphi, and I use some other 3rd party VCL's also, including virtual stringtree, TNT controls, etc. Now I cannot input Russian characters in Word anymore, but I can input English and Chinese....

Since it's a large project I don't know where to start finding the problem, would you give me some generic tips, I'll be appreciated that!

**Update 1**: I found the culprit, it's because the problem use `TntActnList.pas` from the well-known `TNT Controls` package, haven't found a solution to solve it though!

Thank you, and have a nice day!

Comment: Hi Kenny, It's the same problem with Arabic. Don't know about Greek though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue.

If you are using free TNT version (by troy.wolbrink), just comment the following IF block in the TTntApplication.ProcessMessage procedure:

```pascal
if (Msg.message = WM_CHAR)
...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, TMS's version also has the problem. My solution goes further by detecting if the current Window is Word or not.